# How to send a MMS with arduino GSM shield (v2)

Tags: c, arduino, gsm, at-command, mms

Hello Stackoverflow community!

I recently received my 'GSM Shield 2' ([url=http://arduino.org/products/arduino-gsm-shield-2]http://arduino.org/products/arduino-gsm-shield-2[/url]).

I've done some research concerning telecommunication and how it all works, but I'm still new at this so bear with me.

I'm using AT commands, not the GSM library.
I can send/receive sms/phone calls. Yet I'm having some trouble with MMS.
How do I exactly send one with a file? There is no SD-card, so I can't use the File Class from the SD-Library. How do I send my file data?

Any examples, pretty please?

Thank you!

AT MMS documentation: http://www.quectel.com/UploadImage/Downlad/Quectel_GSM_MMS_AT_Commands_Manual_V1.1.pdf

Comment: What documentation do you have that it is capable of sending MMS?

Comment: @r_ahlskog, http://www.quectel.com/UploadImage/Downlad/Quectel_GSM_MMS_AT_Commands_Manual_V1.1.pdf

Comment: That document suggests you look at [4] GSM_FILE_ATC for info on how the file transfers work. I guess it means you issue the `AT+QMMSW=5,1,"data.txt"`` followed by the ascii data you want to include. But without having read that [4] I cannot say if it needs to be length prefixed or something.